# Why is a type registered twice when lifetime manager is specified?

Tags: c#, .net, unity-container

I'm using Unity's *Register by convention* mechanism in the following scenario:

```
public interface IInterface { }

public class Implementation : IInterface { }
```

Given `Implementation` class and its interface I'm running `RegisterTypes` in the following way:

```
unityContainer.RegisterTypes(
    new[] { typeof(Implementation) },
    WithMappings.FromAllInterfaces,
    WithName.Default,
    WithLifetime.ContainerControlled);
```

After this call, `unitContainer` contains three registrations:

- `IUnityContainer` -> `IUnityContainer`  (ok)
- `IInterface` -> `Implementation` (ok)
- `Implementation` -> `Implementation` (???)

When I change the call as follows:

```
unityContainer.RegisterTypes(
    new[] { typeof(Implementation) },
    WithMappings.FromAllInterfaces,
    WithName.Default);
```

The container contains only two registrations:

- `IUnityContainer` -> `IUnityContainer` (ok)
- `IInterface` -> `Implementation` (ok)

(this is the desired behaviour).

After peeking into [Unity's source code](https://github.com/unitycontainer/unity/blob/master/source/Unity/Src/RegistrationByConvention/UnityContainerRegistrationByConventionExtensions.cs), I've noticed that there is some misunderstanding about how `IUnityContainer.RegisterType` should work.

The `RegisterTypes` method works as follows (the comments indicate what are the values in the scenarios presented above):

```
foreach (var type in types)
{
    var fromTypes = getFromTypes(type); // { IInterface }
    var name = getName(type);           // null
    var lifetimeManager = getLifetimeManager(type); // null or ContainerControlled
    var injectionMembers = getInjectionMembers(type).ToArray(); // null

    RegisterTypeMappings(container, overwriteExistingMappings, type, name, fromTypes, mappings);

    if (lifetimeManager != null || injectionMembers.Length > 0)
    {
        container.RegisterType(type, name, lifetimeManager, injectionMembers);   // !
    }
}
```

Because `fromTypes` is not empty, the `RegisterTypeMappings` adds one type mapping: `IInterface` -> `Implementation` (correct).

Then, in case when `lifetimeManager` is not null, the code attempts to change the lifetime manager with the following call:

```
container.RegisterType(type, name, lifetimeManager, injectionMembers);
```

This function's name is completely misleading, because [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee650597.aspx) clearly states that:

> RegisterType a LifetimeManager for the given type and name with the container. No type mapping is performed for this type.

Unfortunately, not only the name is misleading but the documentation is wrong. When debugging this code, I've noticed, that when there is no mapping from `type` (`Implementation` in the scenarios presented above), it is added (as `type` -> `type`) and that's why we end up with three registrations in the first scenario.

I've downloaded Unity's sources to fix the problem, but I've found the following unit test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void RegistersMappingAndImplementationTypeWithLifetimeAndMixedInjectionMembers()
{
    var container = new UnityContainer();
    container.RegisterTypes(new[] { typeof(MockLogger) }, getName: t => "name", getFromTypes: t => t.GetTypeInfo().ImplementedInterfaces, getLifetimeManager: t => new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());

    var registrations = container.Registrations.Where(r => r.MappedToType == typeof(MockLogger)).ToArray();

    Assert.AreEqual(2, registrations.Length);

    // ...
```

- which is almost exactly my case, and leads to my question:

Why is this expected? Is it a conceptual mistake, a unit test created to match existing behaviour but not necessarily correct, or am I missing something important?

I'm using Unity v4.0.30319.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior was fixed in version 5.2.1, as explained in [this article](https://github.com/unitycontainer/unity/wiki/Upgrading-to-Release-v5.2.1):

> Now all information passed to Unity during registration is stored with
>   `FromType` instead of `ToType`. So registering type like this:
>
> ```
> container.RegisterType<ILogger, MockLogger>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(), new InjectionConstructor());
> ```
>
> creates just one registration `ILogger` and associates `LifetimeManager`
>   and all provided `InjectionMemebers` with it. At this point `MockLogger`
>   is still unregistered.

Answer (score 6):

We would need to reach out to the original developers to be sure, but this is what I can only assume as to why it was coded to be this way...

Unity has a feature that allows concrete classes to be resolved even though the type has not been registered.  In this scenario, Unity must make the assumption that you want the default lifetime manager (transient) and no injection members for that concrete type.  If you don't like those default policies, then you need to register the concrete type yourself and specify your customization.

So following that train of thought, when you call RegisterTypes and you do specify a lifetime manager and/or an injection member, then Unity makes the assumption that you want that behavior when resolving by the interface and by the concrete type.  But if you do not specify those policies, then Unity doesn't need the concrete registration because it will fall back to the default behavior when resolving the concrete type.

The only other explanation that I can come up with is for the sake of plugins.  `InjectionMember` is extensible, so Unity thinks you could be passing in a custom behavior for a plugin.  And it therefore makes the assumption that you might want that custom behavior for the plugin to be applied to both the interface and the concrete when you are registering by convention.

---

I understand you are running into this issue while attempting to unit test your application bootstrap.  I'm assuming you are testing to ensure the types you register and only those types are registered.  This is breaking your tests because some tests find this extra concrete registration.

From a unit test perspective, I would argue that you are going beyond the scope of what you are attempting to test.  If you start using plugins, there will be quite a few other registrations that start appearing (like interception policies and behaviors).  That will just add to the problem you are seeing now because of the way you are testing.  I would recommend you change your tests to ensure only a white-list of types are registered and ignore everything else.  Having the concrete (or other additional registrations) is benign to your application.

(e.g. put your interfaces in the white-list and assert each one of those is registered and ignore the fact that the concrete is registered)

Comment: I was writing unit-tests for a bootstrapper of my application and this was very surprising. It makes my tests unreadable - two similar scenarios yield different results. TBH, I don't understand your explanation. Having only one registration allows both: default lifetime manager and the specified one. You have correctly identified the core of the issue: "Unity makes the assumption that you want that behavior when resolving by the interface **and by the concrete type**" - but that's the question: why? What scenario justifies that distinction? I fail to see why would it be helpful in any way.

Comment: Updated answer with another possible reason (plugins) and added a suggestion for changing your unit tests.

Comment: i agree that you should test what you care about. not test about any possible implementation.

Comment: Thanks for your update but this is just not the point. Maybe my unit-tests are not perfect, but they only show the symptom of the fact that Unity's behaviour is unintuitive and incoherent. I'm not asking for ways to make my tests pass - I've already managed to do that - this is not the problem I'm trying to solve here :) The only part of your answer that attempts to address the issue is that it is "for the sake of plugins", but it's unclear how exactly.

Comment: Just because we don't have a full understanding of why the original developers added this behavior does not mean that it is unintuitive and incoherent.  The fact that they added a unit test to ensure this exact behavior is verified tells me that this was fully intentional and there is likely a good reason for it.  Unfortunately, we may have a difficult time getting to the bottom of that reason because the project was (relatively) recently open sourced and we may not be able to reach the original developers to get that reason.  I'll put a feeler out and see if I can reach them.

Comment: The part about intuitiveness is of course subjective. However, it *is incoherent*, because the result is different depending on the way you set lifetime manager. It's true that this incoherence may be intentional (because of the unit test) and this is exactly the reason why the question was asked (as was stated in the question from the beginning) :) Looking forward for your inside-info ;)

Comment: As a side note, how would "accepting only white-listed registrations" help, when you say yourself that other types will be spuriously appearing? :) I prefer to have control over what is in the container (and its child containers), and that's why I'm unit-testing basic features of my bootstrapper :)

Comment: The requirement for your application should be that the interfaces or concretes you **resolve by** are registered.  So I would write a unit test that reflects over your assemblies and gathers a collection of the types that you resolve by and asserts that each of those types are registered.  If other registrations exist, your application shouldn't care.

Comment: @TylerOhlsen Thank you for your suggestions for the unit-tests, I will consider them (seriously I will!). They are however **not the subject of this question**. They only revealed the problem I'm asking about and that I'm interested in.

Comment: @BartoszKP Ok, sure.  I hope I was useful.  I will update this thread if I find out more on the original reasons for why the code is the way it is.

Comment: Unfortunately, my search came up empty handed.  I was not able to reach the original developers.

Comment: @TylerOhlsen Thanks for your effort anyway!

Answer (score 1):

One reason that I can think of for the current behavior is that it reuses the existing Unity functionality/implementation and makes the registration by convention feature fairly easy to implement.

The existing Unity implementation that I'm thinking of is the separation of type mapping and build plan into different policies so if you are working on Unity source code that would be a common way to think about things. Also, from what I've read in the past, the `Registrations` property seems like it was thought of as a second class citizen and not intended to be used for much more than debugging so having another registration might not have seemed to be a big deal. Perhaps those two points put together were part of the decision?

Besides the extra item in the Registrations collections the feature is working in this case.

> Then, in case when `lifetimeManager` is not null, the code attempts to change the lifetime manager with the following call

The `RegisterTypes` method doesn't actually set a `LifetimeManager`. If no `LifetimeManager` is specified then the concrete target type is not explicitly registered and Unity relies on the internal default behavior when creating the object (in this case a default `LifetimeManager` of `TransientLifetimeManager`).

But if anything is specified that could potentially override the defaults (i.e. a `LifetimeManager` or `InjectionMembers`) then the concrete type will be explicitly registered.

It should be possible to get Registration by Convention to work without the extra registration. However, there are some complexities to consider. If a concrete type implements many interfaces there could be multiple mapping registrations for a concrete type but each registration will need it's own lifetime manager instance (they can't be reused). So you could create new lifetime manager instances for each mapping registration but (I believe) only the last lifetime manager would be used. So to avoid unnecessary object creation perhaps only assign the lifetime manager on the last type mapping? That's just one scenario that occurred to me -- there are a variety of scenarios and combinations to consider.

So I think the current implementation is an easy way to implement the feature without having to specifically handle any edge cases with the only side effect being the extra registration. I would guess that was probably part of the thinking at the time (but I wasn't there so it's just a guess).

Comment: The part about being forced to have multiple instances of a default lifetime manager when there are multiple interfaces seems to be a strong argument and the only concrete reason so far. Thanks!